# Can we use Jmeter with Rest Assurred framework?

Tags: jmeter, rest-assured-jsonpath

I need to know if we can implement Jmeter script with the RestAssured framework?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes, given you copy RestAssured .jar file along with dependencies to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you should be able to use its methods from [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or reuse your existing tests via [JUnit Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request)

However it would be much better to use JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers as in this case you will be able to access networking metrics such as Connect Time and Latency, automatic failures on HTTP Status Codes above 399, [Cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), [Headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager),  and [Authorization](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) management, etc.

See [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) article to learn how to build an API test plan using JMeter